# CommandLink with input text

Tags: jsf

I have input text, command link and a logout image in my page. My command link don't work when I use "required" in input text. otherwise it works fine.

Here is my code:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{loginForm.logout}">
    <p:graphicImage value="images/logout.png" alt="Logout" style="width: 50px;height: 50px;" title="Logout"/>
</p:commandLink>
<p:inputText id="fname" required="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command links and buttons submit by default the entire form. In this case, the input field is being validated and gave a "This field is required" validation error (which you should have noticed if you had a `<p:messages autoUpdate="true">` or have paid more love and attention to server log).

However, your logout command seems to stand entirely at its own and all other inputs in the same form have completely nothing to do with the logout command.

There are several solutions, in the order of recommendation:

1. Put the logout command in its own form.

   ```
   <h:form>
       <p:commandLink value="Logout" ... />
   </h:form>
   <h:form>
       Other form.
   </h:form>
   ```

   This makes design technically and semantically the most sense.

   ---
2. Tell the logout command to process only itself on submit.

   ```
   <p:commandLink value="Logout" process="@this" ... />
   ```

   This defaults namely to `@form` which means "the entire form". Use this only if a separate form is absolutely not an option for some reason (e.g. due to poor CSS design and/or not being well versed in basic HTML/CSS).

   ---
3. Abuse the `immediate` attribute.

   ```
   <p:commandLink value="Logout" immediate="true" ... />
   ```

   This will bypass all inputs which do *not* have the `immediate` attribute. But this would fail when there are actually inputs which *do* need the `immediate` attribute to prioritize validation.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the action is blocked during the validation phase. Add `immediate="true"` to your `commandLink` and it should work fine.

For more info see [here](http://www.javabeat.net/qna/497-what-is-the-use-of-immediate-attribute/).